# iPhone - Data URI's (css background images) only work when connected to WIFI

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, data-uri

I've created a mobile web application for use by Android and iPhone devices, after testing I was happy that everything worked perfectly and so decided to try optimising it a little.

I decided I would use data uri's in my css file as all the images are small 16x16px png images.

While testing with my iPhone connected to the Internet via WiFi the images load fine, however when connecting using the mobile data connection images do not load.

Looking through the Apache error log I see that for some reason the image is being requested as a file (and is not being found), although using WiFi there are no errors...

```
File does not exist: /www/min/data:image, referer: http://mysite.com/login/
```

The CSS I am using is as follows...

```
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAA5CAYAAAD3PEFJAAAAUUlEQVQYV4XMyw1AABQF0ePpQCNK0Ke+lCEkFmLjWRHx3dzcZCaDItV1m5GZgn0y1+M9AWfl4r2Cv/Jd+fDWN/AXgCyrqukCY6APDIEpMAeWDc7zXPFRLR43AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
```

I've tried everything I can thing of, not using css shorthand/using css shorthand, different mime types, not using Google Minify, but all to no avail.  But this still does not explain why it all works perfectly over WiFi.

The Android device also works perfectly as do Firefox, Chrome and the desktop version of Safari. Also when loading the actual PNG image files (as opposed to embedding images using data URIs) the images load fine.

If anybody can shed some light on this I will be eternally grateful, most things I can work out but this has me completely stumped!

Comment: I should note that this is using an iPhone 3g iOS 4.2.1 on the O2 network in the UK.  My Android device is a HTC Hero on T-Mobile.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be related to O2 image compression, if the following tutorial can be relied on... http://www.edandersen.com/2008/07/13/iphone-o2-fix-the-image-compression/

Comment: This problem seems also not to be related to a particular web server set-up.  Anyone wishing to try out my test document can find it here... http://daledavies.co.uk/datauri/

Comment: I tested with my AT&T phone from US and the URL shows content just fine. I guess you have a problem with your provider. Sorry! you might want to work with O2?

Comment: I think I'm going to have to, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a solution, more of a work around...

It seems after much messing around that the only way I can find to get this to work (usin go2) is to use inline styles for css containing the data uri's.

However, my intention was to embed the images into the external stylesheet so it (and the embedded images) would become cached, embedding images into the html document itself means I cannot cache the images so they must be loaded with every request.

As always, if there is a better way I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if the carrier is blocking data URI schemes or plain does not support it. I would try to tether the laptop with a mobile connection and see if data URIs work. Hmm, but then you would not have seen the request fail on your web server logs. I also recommend seeing the request coming in to the server using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) and see if there is a difference in requests between the one from mobile connection vs. wifi (specifically the headers being sent in the two requests)

Comment: Thanks, I did think about the possibility of data being rewritten by the carrier, stripping out data uri's perhaps. But as you say I might not see the error in my logs. Only my live server is internet facing at the moment so I cant install Wireshark on it, but I did knock together a script to dump the http headers into a database table, unfortunately with the exception of the HTTP_VIA and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR headers added by our proxy the rest are identical.

Comment: Did you also try tethering a laptop and navigating to the server? That might show if the problem is with the carrier.  It does seem like the carrier is somehow making the image request to be treated as a File request than a data request (not sure how.. :( )

Comment: Any luck? This is an interesting problem.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I wont be able to try that as I cant jailbreak the iPhone.  I'll do some more research tonight.

Comment: Well, I was unable to tether the iPhone.  But I consider that maybe I'd made a mistake somewhere in the css file so I created a seperate test page.  This exhibits the same behaviour, I did also manage to find a friend with an iPhone on a different carrier and his worked fine.  Now I'm confused, we are encouraged to use data uri's when optimising mobile web apps (http://code.google.com/speed/articles/mobile.html).